# Remotely access Parse dashboard

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I managed to configure stand alone Parse server for my Android app using ubuntu server and mongoDB. And now Parse released its open source dashboard for parse server which I am able to setup but getting error in accessing it remotely.

As it says "Parse Dashboard can only be remotely accessed via HTTPS". I have almost no experience of developing web app. I have tried changing http to https in url but it didn't worked!

I have also tried adding username and password for basic auth, but it didn't worked either! Here's link for parse dashboard

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard

Comment: Have you configured your ssl certificate? Can your server accept connections on the https port?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the dashboard like this:

```
export PARSE_DASHBOARD_ALLOW_INSECURE_HTTP=1
npm run dashboard
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have tried your solution and then it prompt for username and password and I was able to access dashboard page, but now it's simply loading and nothing else happing. Any guess? My server is running absolutely fine!

Comment: Have you configured the app and a user in parse-dashboard-config.json?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I set up the parse server through heroku. I tried antsyawn's suggestion, it did not work. The github to parse-dashboard just updated a little more.

Now you should:

```
npm install -g parse-dashboard
parse-dashboard --appId yourAppId --masterKey yourMasterKey --serverURL "https://example.com/parse" --appName optionalName
```

They did suggested to add `--allowInsecureHTTP=1`

Nevertheless, I tried all that as well and its not working. May be you can try this too since you set up your server differently(it might work).

Comment: I tried that but now its loading and nothing happening. Are you able to run parse dashboard? BTW I have implemented parse server standalone.

Answer (score 0):

im working with ParseServer And ParseDashboard to Start we cant create confused about two.

For me , more important is ParseDashboard, And yes you can acess Remotely, firstly you need create a hack direct in code to do that.

To run parse dashboard without problems follow this steps. 
`git clone git@github.com:ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard.git
cd parse-dashboard
npm install`

After this! after!...

`npm run dashboard`

This screen will be showed to you...
When this image is running you can acess by url your serverIp:4040 will show dashboard.

[dashboard is running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxpzl.png)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @xiaowoo worked for me. For a visual, I watched this video

[Install Parse Server and Parse Dashboard to Digital Ocean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agXcuQhWCoU)

In summary, here is what I ended up running:

```
parse-dashboard --appId MyApp --masterKey mysupersecretmasterkey --serverURL "https://198.58.10.23/parse" --appName TestApp --allowInsecureHTTP=1
```

Server response:

```
The dashboard is now available at http://0.0.0.0:4040/
```

Browse to your dashboard:

```
http://198.58.10.23:4040
```